# M:N conversion using generics

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, type-conversion

I want to convert a bunch of types to a bunch of other types. E.g., I have four types, `SourceA`, `SourceB`, `TargetA` and `TargetB`, I'll have the following conversions:

- SourceA => TargetA
- SourceA => TargetB
- SourceB => TargetA
- SourceB => TargetB

Basically, conversion is a little bit more advanced than a simple cast. It requires a very own strategy for each of the cases above.

What I would like to *avoid* is having several methods which contain the types in the method **name**, so I do **not** want something such as:

`ConvertAtoA`

or similar things. The reason why I do not want this is because the types are then used as strings, not as types themselves, so whenever I go to rename a type there is no refactoring support. Supposed I rename `SourceA` to `SourceXyz`, the method will not get renamed automatically, but I will have to do this manually.

What I would like to have is a generic way of expressing this, mainly to get refactoring support. So basically something such as:

`Convert<SourceA, TargetA>(mySourceValue)`

The problem here is that I end up with a generic `Convert<TSource, TTarget>`method which contains **ALL** the logic for **ALL** types (which is a bad idea for obvious reasons).

I have already taken a look at various design patterns, including visitor, strategy and chain of responsibility, but none of them caught attraction. Anyway, I am not sure whether I missed a point there.

How could I solve this issue?

Basically, the two main targets are:

- Having separate conversion logic for each combination (no complex methods)
- Having refactoring support (no types as strings)

Any ideas?

**Update 1:** I have considered using AutoMapper, but I am not sure whether it works the way I want. What I can do for sure is set up a custom converter, such as

```
Mapper.CreateMap<string, DateTime>().ConvertUsing(new DateTimeTypeConverter());
```

but then again I have the type `DateTime` as part of the converter name. I know that I can also use a lambda expression here, but this again makes the code ugly, because it will become very long. Anyway, I fear that I can't have everything ...

**Update 2:** You could ease the problem by putting on the constraint that there is always a `Dictionary<string, string>` (although with different contents) on the left and a custom class on the right. So what I would like to end up with is an extension method such as

```
dictionary.To<TargetA>()
```

but without the need to put all the logic for converting to different types into the `To<T>` method.

Comment: have you tried AutoMapper ?

Comment: See the update of the question ;-)

Comment: You could use the FactoryPattern to get an apropriate Converter.

Comment: Could you please provide a small example on how I would set up the factory? (I know what a factory is, but I don't have the slightest idea on how I might set up the factory given the constraints above). It would be very helpful :-)

Comment: You could also (though this may be a bit confusing to a casual reader of your code) setup [implicit conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2(v=vs.110).aspx) for your types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create extension method, which will create target type and then delegate filling that object to some method based on generic parameter type:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T ConvertTo<T>(this Dictionary<string, string> dictionary)
        where T : new()
    {
        dynamic target = new T();
        return (T)Extensions.FillFrom(target, dictionary);
    }

    private static object FillFrom(this object obj, 
                                   Dictionary<string, string> dictionary)
    {
        var message = "Conversion to " + obj.GetType() + " is not supported.";
        throw new NotSupportedException(message);
    }

    private static TargetA FillFrom(this TargetA target, 
                                    Dictionary<string, string> dictionary)
    {
        // throw exception if required keys not found
        target.Foo = dictionary["foo"];
        return target;
    }

    private static TargetB FillFrom(this TargetB target, 
                                    Dictionary<string, string> dictionary)
    {
        // throw exception if required keys not found
        target.Bar = dictionary["bar"];
        return target;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var targetA = dictionary.ConvertTo<TargetA>();
```

Same approach you can use with some converter class (if you don't like extension methods). Also you can make `FillFrom` methods public. Than you can use them like:

```
var target A = new TargetA().FillFrom(dictionary);
```

Comment: @GoloRoden so, your types are completely different, like string and DateTime?

Comment: Yes, actually they are 'Dictionary<string, string>' on the left and a custom defined class on the right.

Comment: @GoloRoden then I don't think mapping is what you need. What about serializing your objects into string? E.g. with `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SourceA);` Btw what you are trying to implement?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little more? I don't see the relation between mine comment and yours.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Why `Dictionary<string, string>`? What are you storing in that dictionary?

Comment: I am calling a web service on SAP and `Dictionary<string, string>` is what I get as a result. Depending on the return type, the dictionary contains different keys and values. I need to convert the content of this dictionary to an object, and I know (as I do the call to the web service) which type I need to convert to. Hence I have m kinds of dictionaries and n types of custom types. Unfortunately, it's not 1:n, it's m:n, as some dictionaries may be converted to various types.

Comment: @GoloRoden do your target classes have parameterless constructors?

Comment: @GoloRoden no problem :) nice thing is that all conversion code is now in one specific to target type method

Answer (score 1):

I got it :-)

Basically, my problem was that I was not able to do method overloading by a generic type parameter. Hence I made a virtue out of necessity and switched to using the `TryXXX` pattern.

My solution now looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main ()
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string> {
                { "a", "b" }
            };

            Dog dog;
            if (dict.TryGet (out dog))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dog.Color);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static bool TryGet(this Dictionary<string, string> dictionary, out Dog dog)
        {
            dog = new Dog();
            dog.Color = "black / white";
            return true;
        }
    }

    public class Dog
    {
        public string Color { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This way I do not have the type `Dog` anywhere in a method name, but I can have a separate method for each type I want to convert to.

Adding a new type means just adding the type, and adding a new overload for the extension method `TryGet`.

The trick is to use the `out` parameter for method overloading, which works perfectly fine :-).